# ffmpeg upscale 4/3 video to fullhd by crop vertically

Tags: ffmpeg, crop, scaling

I have some video 4:3 generally are 1280x960 and other resolutions.

I like to upscale it to 1920x1080 and crop vertically to avod horizontal black borders.

I have found this commmand:

```
ffmpeg -i intro_NR_Upscale_4x.mp4 -filter:v "pad=ih*16/9:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -c:a copy intro_NR_Upscale_4x_ouput.mp4
```

but not work and continue to show horizontal black borders.

There is a command line that upscale low resolution 4:3 video to 16:9 and crop it ?

Thanks !

Comment: crop=iw:iw*9/16:0:0,scale=1920:1080

Comment: thank you it work partially crop vertically but asymmetrical. The video in not centered but crop only the bottom part. To work must crop equally on the top and bottom.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry :) crop=iw:iw*9/16:0:(ih-oh)/2